# Copy multiple files from different folders to a different destination folder

Tags: excel, vba

On a daily basis, I copy multiple files from a specified locations to destination folders.

It becomes a tedious task to go inside each folder, select the files and paste to the destination folder.

Note: The full file name changes daily. I want to use a part of the file name.

For example - With ABC_REPOOO15_DDMMYYY I want to use REP00015 as this would be constant.

```
A1                 B1                                   C1
File name        Source folder                      Destination folder
REP00015     C:\Users\Sam's Lps\Desktop\Soucre      C:\Users\Sam's Lps\Desktop\Destination
```

I tried the below code

```
Sub movefiles()

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the original folder:"

    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the destination folder:"

    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
            Kill xSPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code attached will worked as soon as you have all the filenames to copy in one excel datasheet. Is it your case? If it is, that one works.

If it is not your case, then create an Excel File Macro Enabled on your destination directory and just add this macro:

```
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
Dim xVal,MyPath, MyFileName, Aux As String
Dim x

x = Shell("cmd /k dir ABC_REPOOO15*.* /b >list.txt", vbHide)

MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
MyFileName = "list.txt"
Aux = "TEXT;" & MyPath & "/" & MyFileName

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Aux _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "list"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

On Error Resume Next

Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", , ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)

If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the original folder:"

If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the destination folder:"

If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

For Each xCell In xRg
    xVal = xCell.Value
    If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
        FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        Kill xSPathStr & xVal
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

That macro will create a list of your files in your excel datasheet.
You can choose your files, destination and final directories and done.

Anyhow, you can custom this macro for some other files. F.e.

"dir *.TMP /b >list.txt"

To get all the *.TMP files in your directory.

Hope it helps.